# find y mv en una sola comanda

Tags: linux, terminal

Quisiera saber como puedo usar las comandas **find** y **mv** en **una sola linea** para primero encontrar un tipo de archivo y despues moverlos a un directorio en la **terminal de linux**.

Comment: ¿qué intentaste? ¿Qué caso concreto buscas? ¿O es más bien una pregunta genérica? Dale a [edit] para aportar más detalles

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso del siguiente comando: `find /ruta/archivo -name "suNombre.ext" -exec mv -t /ruta/a/mover {} \;`

Si quieres tener más información de cada comando, solo debes hacer uso de `man name_comando` y te muestra sus opciones